# tmhOAuth not working - Twitter API 1.1

Tags: php, api, twitter

so my websites just stopped working an hour ago with this code:

string(200) "{"errors": [{"message": "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.", "code": 68}]}"

I'm using tmhOAuth PHP Class.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Yesterday twitter stopped supporting API v1. https://twitter.com/twitterapi/status/344567017875046400. tmhOAuth doesn't support v1.1 out of the box.

Comment: Thanks, so what can I do?

Comment: You can use the the tutorial here to use an alternative library, if you have that option: http://www.webdevdoor.com/php/authenticating-twitter-feed-timeline-oauth/. You can also download this WordPress plugin: http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/social-networks-auto-poster-facebook-twitter-g, they say they have updated it to support 1.1. They seem to be using tmOAuth, the file is there but not sure. Look at the main file NextScripts_SNAP.php file and see how it is publishing posts to twitter.

Comment: Please post the answer if you figure it out, I'm in the same boat...

Answer (score 4):

Just replace 1/status -> 1.1/status etc
More details: https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth/issues/132